# Better architecture than inheritance on Activities that implement posts

Tags: android, api, inheritance, design-patterns, posts

I have this following architecture for a few activities and a fragment that allow a user to post messages.

The messages have a Parent-Child relationship where a Parent post (a feed) might have child posts (comments).

I am wondering if this would be the proper architecture to implement the above requirements. There is a lot of data being passed back and forth between the activities, an EventBus, a Marshall object, and the client.

On a high level is there a better way to implement posts?

I have a few hunches:

1. Use a service instead of a Parent Activity
2. Use the Model View Presenter pattern
3. Use polymorphism with interfaces?

That's all I have so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

1) use the MVP pattern

2) make sure your use POJOs for passing data, and then 'add' to the POJOs the ability to Marshall/Demarshall(breaks some people's definition of 'pojo', but it really makes the code using it cleaner)

3) Have the POJO also convert to/from ContentValues/cursor if you are using ContentProvider(s) also

(2 and 3 helps centralize the requirements for what all needs to know the 'specifics' of the POJO's data)